# Существует ли какой-нибудь урезанный exchangeдля разработчиков?

Tags: c#, .net, exchange

Программа должна активно работать с почтой exchange: обрабатывать почту и все такое.

Нет ли в природе какого-нибудь легковесного сервера, который можно было бы поставить без лишних заморочек и настроек?

Comment: ну разве что вот так https://products.office.com/en-us/exchange/exchange-online

Comment: Хм... Это к сожалению платно=(

Answer (score 0):

Есть возможность создать учетку для разработчиков. Год бесплатно.

[Office Dev center](https://dev.office.com/devprogram)

Либо развернуть триальный exchange на VM и по окончании триала откатываться на снэпшот до его установки.